# Vary the color of quivver arrows depending on third value

Tags: matlab, colors, plot

I am trying to create a pcolor, which has a quiver (representing velocity vectors) superimposed.  I've managed to achieve this, but now ideally I'd like to color each quiver error depending on that point's velocity in the z-direction.

I know, of course, that it's possible to change the color of *all* the arrows, but is it possible to change the color of them independently..?

Thanks in advance,

Adam

Comment: You want to apply a colormap to your arrow?

Comment: yes, based on a third number.  I have seen lots of things in the fileexchange that do this based on the *magnitude* of the arrow, but not based on a third number.

Comment: You maybe can just change the code on the FileExchange to only take the z-value no ? Can you please provide the link of this FileExchange, maybe I can have a look on it.

Comment: this seems like the best bet, which seems to be editable just by changing where the value comes from.  I'll see if it's possible.  otherwise, a simpler solution would be handy!

Comment: Yes, I think this can be the best solution too. If you don't get it, tell me and maybe we can find another solution like you said.

Comment: doesn't seem obvious how that would work, as it seems to rely on drawing a canvas behind.  perhaps I'm missing something, though!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38444/discussion-between-alexandre-bizeau-and-tiswas)

Answer (score 0):

Test out quiverc. Looks like it does exactly what you're after.

https://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3225-quiverc

The alternative, hack solution, would be to do a sequence of quiver plots, trigger a hold, redo the quiver plot with n-1 items in it, and iterate. Not pretty, but it would work.

Comment: Sorry, that works on the magnitude, rather than the z value. Regardless, you could edit it such that the magnitude it read in was just the z value.